# What is the most efficient way to run programs in Emacs after M-x compile 'ing

Tags: emacs

I have started using M-x compile to compile programs in say, C.

What is the most efficient way to run the executable e.g. a.out. At the moment I'm using M-! ./a.out. Basically, what is the best code-compile-run procedure to follow?

Almost all the tutorials mention how compilation is done, but I haven't seen one which addressed this issue?

Thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often just append the run command at the end of the build:

```
M-x compile RET gmake && ./a.out
```

The `&&` will tell the shell to only invoke `a.out` when the compilation is successful.

Though I often run the program from an existing shell buffer (<kbd>M-x shell</kbd>), or from one of many shells that I manage with package very much like [screen](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen).

Comment: What should I do if the program requires user input? The compilation buffer is read-only. I don't want to have to open ansi-term or something.

Comment: @Samuel If there's user input, then I definitely use a *shell* buffer.

Comment: So there's no escaping it then... 
Thanks,
Samuel

Comment: @Samuel One nice thing about running from a shell from w/in Emacs is that Emacs will keep track of what you've typed as input to the program (as opposed to a standard shell, which only remembers what you've typed into the shell itself).  This allows you to re-use what you've already typed.

Comment: Which built-in is the best? I've tried eshell and ansi-term. Ansi-term makes the error messages of gcc look weird (accented characters, slashes etc), so I use eshell.
Will have to figure out how to fix it later...

Comment: @Samuel I generally continue to use `M-x compile` for the compilation, and the shell for running.  As far as which shell, I'm still stuck on tcsh, but any (bash, tcsh, csh, ksh) will work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with the last question; what I meant was, how do you use bash (or any of the other shells) in emacs? Do you M-x shell, M-x eshell, M-x ansi-term M-x term or something else. I would like to know which one of these is the best.

Comment: @Samuel I use `M-x shell` as the answer says.  :)

Comment: eshell is a much better shell.  Also, `&&` doesn't work on windows.  (But everything in eshell does!)

Comment: @jrockway I'll have to start giving eshell a chance.

Answer (score 3):

I use the extension [smart-compile+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/smart-compile+.el), it allows you to specify
quite convenient rules depending on the name of the file/buffer you are editing.
For example, in my .emacs I specify the following rule for when running
smart-compile in a project euler file:

```
(add-to-list 'smart-compile-alist
         '("euler.*\\.[Cc]+[Pp]*$" . "g++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wreturn-type %f -lm -lgmpxx -lgmp -o ../bin/%n && time ../bin/%n")
         )
```

First you specify the filename pattern for the rule, then the path where it should be executed, then the compile command.
In the above case, I add && time ../bin/%n to run the program directly after it has been successfully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice is for interactive development; code, load files into the REPL, resolve errors (With C-x `, just as with M-x compile), and then play with the code in the REPL.

If that's not an option, I use eshell as a generic REPL.  Compile, switch to eshell, run, test, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule to your makefile to compile **and run** your program, so <kbd>M-x compile</kbd> will compile and run, test, valgrind-test... whatever